# pandas dataframe plot option and use a defined color map

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and I want to make a stacked plot. The command that i use is:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['sample', 'species']).size().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()).unstack()
df1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap=cmap, ax=f.gca())
```

The plot looks good but I would like to always the same color for the same species from a different dataset. To do so, I build a table where I link the speceis name to a RGB color. however, I`m not able to link the name of the species in the plot to the color.

How can i do it? can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach - include all `species` values in every dataset. Thus `pandas` will make all the linking automatically. 2 steps needed - follow comments. Hope it's close to your expectations.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

num = 100

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample': [random.randrange(10) for dummy in range(num)],
    'species': [random.choice('abcdi') for dummy in range(num)]})
dfg1 = (
      df1
      .groupby(['sample', 'species'])
      .size()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()).unstack())

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sample': [random.randrange(10) for dummy in range(num)],
    'species': [random.choice('defghi') for dummy in range(num)]})
dfg2 = (
      df2
      .groupby(['sample', 'species'])
      .size()
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()).unstack())

# step 1 - get all values of species
all_columns = set(dfg1.columns) | set(dfg2.columns)

# step 2 - add all species to every dataset
for dfg in [dfg1, dfg2]:
    for col in all_columns.difference(set(dfg.columns)):
        dfg[col] = 0  # zeros for all added species
        dfg.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)  # sort columns of every dataset

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax1.set_title('data_1')
dfg1.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax1, cmap='rainbow')
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
ax2.set_title('data_2')
dfg2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax2, cmap='rainbow')
```